# Adding a post using Blogger API not working

Tags: java, android, post, blogger, google-blogger-api

i am using Google Blogger API to create posts programmatically in a blog I created. I am using the code below to try and create a new post but it is not adding a new blog

The code:

```
private void addPost(){
new Thread (()->{
String mUserId = "MY_BLOGGER_POST_ID_HERE";
          String mYApiKey = "MY_API_KEY";
          String Authorization = "SOME_CHARACTERS_AND.apps.googleusercontent.com_HERE";

            

              final JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
              obj.put("id", mUserId);

              final JSONObject requestBody = new JSONObject();
              requestBody.put("kind", "blogger#post");
              requestBody.put("blog", obj);
              requestBody.put("title", "TestingTheBlogOneTwo");
              requestBody.put("content", "ContentExample");

              DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
              final HttpPost request = new HttpPost("https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/" + mUserId + "/posts?key=" + mYApiKey + "");
              request.addHeader("Authorization", Authorization);
              request.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
              request.setEntity(new StringEntity(requestBody.toString()));
    
              HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
              if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != 200){
                  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "status code " + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              }
              else {
                  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "done: ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

              }
}).start();
}
```

But it's not adding any post

•Is this the right way to add a post using Blogger Api?

•Are my omitting anything?

*Please what are my getting wrong.

Any help will be appreciated will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

**Update:** The app is not crashing and no new blog is being added

Comment: **i added a toast to know if the button is working properly but the toast is not showing.** -  OK - so your button is not wired up correctly. Show full context of how the button is set up.

Comment: how are getting Authorization token?

Answer (score 0):

> •Is this method correct?

To know if this method is "correct" we would have to know what your definition of "correct" is. Since you've added no information beyond "here's a function", we cannot answer this question.

> Cause it's returning null.

No, it's not. You've defined this as:

```
Private void addPost(){
```

Ignoring the fact that `Private` (with a capital `P`) is not a thing, your method return type is `void` - which means it returns *nothing*. Thus, by definition, it cannot be "returning null".

---

Edit:

> •Is this the right way to add a post using Blogger Api?

Have you read through [the Blogger API documentation](https://developers.google.com/blogger/docs/3.0/getting_started) and done everything as it explains?

If so, then *yes*. If not, then *no*.

> Are my omitting anything?

Not sure how anyone is supposed to know if *you're* omitting anything.

Buddy - what is your actual *problem*? "Am I doing this right" or "Am I missing anything" are not good questions. What is happening to cause you to come to SO with this question? Is there an error? Is there a crash? Does your laptop blow up?

Comment: I have updated the question **P** is a typo. It's is **private void addPost()** .

Comment: Your updated question is as vague as your original question.